# How can I prove that a cactus graph is planar?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, planar-graphs

I've been struggling with the following question:

> Prove that a [cactus graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph) is planar

I've worked out something, but I'm not sure if I'm right or wrong:

Consider every cycle of the cactus graph separately: the number vertices is equal to the number of edges, because every edge contributes to $1$ cycle. The number of faces is equal to $2$ (inside and outside the cycle). If we fill in Eulers formula ($V-E+F=2$), we get: $2=2$. Considering every subgraph is planar, we can assume that our cactus graph is planar. Q.E.D.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be helpful for others to include the definition of a cactus graph here: " connected graph in which any two simple cycles have at most one vertex in common".

Comment: Not a proof but a computation (*Mathematica*):  `DeleteDuplicates[PlanarGraphQ /@ (GraphData[#] & /@ GraphData["Cactus"])]` (* True *)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Your idea is natural, but doesn't quite work. It's possible for every proper subgraph of $G$ to be planar, even though $G$ itself is not planar. $K_{3,3}$ is an example of this phenomenon, for instance.

Here's a slick proof. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph#Properties), every minor of a cactus graph is cactus. We also know by [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) that a graph is nonplanar if and only if it has either $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor.

So if we can show that $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are both noncactus, then every cactus graph avoids them. But that means every cactus graph is planar.

Of course, it's quite easy to see that $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ *are* both noncactus. Do you see why? In each case you should be able to find an edge which is contained in multiple cycles.

---

I hope this helps ^_^